# Order of two vectors to maximise the norm

Tags: permutations, normed-spaces, vectors

Given vectors ${\bf a} = [a_1, \dots , a_n]^T$ and ${\bf b} = [b_1, \dots , b_n]^T$, a permutation $\pi$ acting on $[1, \dots ,n]$ and defining ${\bf b}^{\pi} = [b_{\pi(1)}, \dots , b_{\pi(n)}]^T$, how do we find $\pi$ that ***maximises*** the L2 norm of $|{\bf a} - {\bf b}^\pi|$?

I can see how this could be done using linear program techniques by treating it as an [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) but was wondering if there may be a better way (an explanation of why there is no better way would also suffice).

For example if we wanted to find $\pi$ ***minimising*** the L2 norm, we can simply choose the permutation $\pi$ that orders w.r.t < the vector ${\bf b}$ in the same ordering as ${\bf a}$ and this is easy to prove by considering quadratic expressions.

Comment: What happens if you take the permutation that orders $b$ the opposite way to $a$?

Comment: It seems as though this may be the answer but I can't see how to prove it elegantly. Its not too hard to show that the oppositely ordered vector ${\bf c}$ say, always gives a norm greater than ${\bf c}^{\pi}$ where $\pi$ only swaps two values and keeps the others the same but I don't see a nice way to generalise (although intuitively I think it should).